# Name of comic/graphic novel with circus people

Tags: story-identification, comics

Apologies if this isn't the right site to ask this on.

Can someone tell me the name of a comic, or series of comics, the first one being about a group of people from a circus, including clowns and a two-headed woman?

From what I recall they drive around whilst drinking, and possibly one of their number dies during it.

The story stuck with me even though I can't remember a lot of the details.

Comment: I don't really see how this fits in with sci-fi or fantasy. Was she really two-headed or was it just some kind of trick?

Comment: @Richard: Really two-headed, IIRC.

Comment: Austin Powers: There are only two things in this world that scare me and one is nuclear war.
Basil: What’s the other?
Austin Powers: Huh?
Basil: What’s the other thing that scares you?
Austin Powers: Carnies. Circus folk. Nomads, you know. Smell like cabbage. Small hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be Dave Louapre and Dan Sweetman's [*Beautiful Stories for Ugly Children,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FWE3II) published in 1989. It's a magic realism/urban fantasy B/W graphic novel series with a good deal of [Maybe Magic, Maybe Mundane.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MaybeMagicMaybeMundane)

I'm trying to dig up my copy.

Comment: That's it! I remember the name of the comic and the content being quite melancholic

Comment: Damn. Beat me to it. I was so excited to see a question about this great series.